# How can I reproduce this?

Tags: tables

How can I reproduce this table?( ignore the text allignment below) [image]?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have.  See [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Comment: By the way, the table cell items are badly aligned ;-)

Comment: This is a very poor question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\sffamily
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|} \hline
  Sample header & Sample header  \\ \hline\hline
   Key & Value \\ 
  Key 2 & Value 2\\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Since you didn't give any column specifications, I wrote a simple `tabular`.